# Getting a file from "file://A/"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I get a file from external path same as `"file://A/B/C/D/"`
In local machine I have access to the path of "file://" but the user has not access.
Now I want to read some files from "file://A/B/C/D/" and make downloadable for user.

How can I do it?

(current directory is "https://localhost:44331/")

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadDocument(string berichtsnummer)
{
   var constantPath = "file://A/B/C/D/";
   using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(constantPath))
   {

      MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
      memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);

     fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
     return File(fileStream, "application/octet-stream");
   }
}
```

when I click to download link, I get this error:

> "IOException: The syntax for filename, directory name, or volume label
>   is incorrect:"
>   [[image: IOException[1]]

**A view of path "file://A/B/C/D/":**

[image: File path]

Comment: You seem to have the code already so I am not sure what the problem is?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The `file:` URI scheme is one that's accessible only on the local machine. asp.net server code never sees any access to such URIs, nor does it need to do anything (nor have the ability to) intercede when the client's local file system is accessed.

Comment: Are you trying to download a "random" file from the client's machine? You fortunately cannot do that! Note that when you try it locally it may seem to work, because "client" and "server" machine are actually the same.

Comment: You are using a URI with local file IO methods. Why? As for the rest of the code, the main benefit of a stream is that you don't have to load or write everything in one huge buffer. You could copy one stream's contents to another's simply using `Stream.CopyTo`. And finally, `File` can already work with local files or streams. Using `memorystream` the way you do here is pointless

Comment: This sounds a case of the XY problem. You have a problem X and think Y is the solution so when you run into trouble you ask about Y, not X. In this case why not just write `return File(path,"application/octet-stream")` ? Why the URI, the memory stream and the explicit stream lengths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's important to change the constantPath to `"\\\\A\\B\\C\\D\\"`

```
private string[] GetListOfDocumentLink()
{
   string path = string.Empty;
   string constantPath = "\\\\A\\B\\C\\D\\";

   string folderName = string.Empty;
   string year = string.Empty;
   // determine folderName and year.  

   path = constantPath
        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()
        + folderName
        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()
        + year;

        var filter = Berichtsnummer + "*.pdf";

        string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, filter);
        return allFiles;
}
```

Now you can send the `path` to `DownloadDocument` method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadDocument(string path)
{
   byte[] berichtData = null;
   FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
   long berichtFileLength = fileInfo.Length;
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
   berichtData = br.ReadBytes((int)berichtFileLength);

   return File(berichtData, MimeTypeHelper.GetMimeType("pdf"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A local file path is not "file://". You can read the file normally using the local file path as

```
var path = "C:\\...";
```

and then send to content to the client browser.

If the file is not on the local machine, the only way is to access it using a network share. You can then use UNC paths, like

```
var path = @"\\Server\Path\...";
```